# SVG Checkbox remove padding

Tags: html, css, svg, material-ui

I trying to override MUI5 checkbox CSS fields, this is the current status:

[image]

My CSS classes are:

```
 MuiCheckbox: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        backgroundColor: "white",
      },
    },
  },
},
```

And the structure is:

```html
 <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-7w1q46-MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="CheckBoxIcon">
 <path id="kk" d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
 </svg>
```

My question is how can i remove the white border without removing the backgroundColor?(without the backgroundColor the inner check is transparent)

Comment: Use this viewBox instead: `viewBox="3 3 18 18"`

Comment: Is there a way to do so from CSS? the path is part of third-library component @enxaneta

Comment: @Ar26 there is no other way you can update the viewbox property of mui icons, but you can refer SvgIcon component where you can use your custom svg icon and provide viewbox property. I am not sure that will help you as you are using checkbox which is conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Considering I can't override the viewBox values I found a simple solution

my updated CSS override:

```
 MuiCheckbox: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        path: {
          transform: "translate(-2px, -2px) scale(1.2)",
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```